# Only Bind certain properties of the navigation properties inside my action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have the following 2 model classes:-

```
 public Submission()
        {
            SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Npi { get; set; }
        public bool Independent { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }


public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
    {
        public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }
        public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
    }
```

and i created the following view model:-

```
 public class SubmissionCreate
    {
        public Submission Submission {set; get;}
        public IList<SubmissionQuestion> SubmissionQuestion { set; get; }

        public IList<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { set; get; }

    }
```

then inside my view i only need to submit back the following fields:-

```
@model LandingPageFinal3.ViewModels.SubmissionCreate
<form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Submission.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Submission.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Submission.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Submission.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Submission.LastName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Submission.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Submission.Npi" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Submission.Npi" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Submission.Npi" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Submission.Independent" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Submission.Independent)
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Submission.Comment" class="control-label"></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="Submission.Comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Submission.Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div id="additionalInfo">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubmissionQuestion.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <label>@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label><br />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question" hidden />
                        <textarea asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].SubmissionQuestionId" hidden />
                        <br />
                    }
                </div>
```

so i define the following binding inside my post action method, to only bind the fields inside my view, as follow:-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind(Submission.FirstName,Submission.LastName,Submission.Npi,Submission.Independent" +
            "Submission.Comment,SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Answer,SubmissionQuestionSubmission.SubmissionQuestionId")] SubmissionCreate sc )
        {
```

but the `sc.Submission` and the `sc.SubmissionQuestionSubmission` will be null inside my action method... so not sure what is the minimum binding i should define, to prevent hacking our application by posting back extra info and navigation properties other than the ones defined in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `bind` to bind only the fields that appear in your view.

In fact, your view has set the `name` attribute for the fields you need to display, so 
`SubmissionCreate sc` will only bind the corresponding fields in the view when accepting.

Just use this code to receive:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SubmissionCreate sc)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

---

### Update

Since you only bound some fields in the view, you only need to exclude the SubmissionQuestion field value：

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Submission", "SubmissionQuestionSubmission")]SubmissionCreate sc)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If you want to be more precise, you can bind the fields you need to the `Submission` and `SubmissionQuestionSubmission` classes separately, as follows:

```
   [Bind("FirstName,LastName,Npi,Independent,Comment")]
    public class Submission
    {
        public Submission()
        {
            SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Npi { get; set; }
        public bool Independent { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }


   [Bind("Answer,SubmissionQuestionId")]
    public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }

        public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain your point in more details, i want to use Bind to prevent posting back extra info and data

Comment: @testtestte， I have update my post, you can try it.